# How to scale a NumericMatrix in-place with Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, matrix, rcpp, syntactic-sugar

This is what I'm doing now

```
library(Rcpp)

A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
rownames(A) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
colnames(A) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

cppFunction('
void scaleMatrix(NumericMatrix& A, double x) {
    A = A * x;
}')
```

Unfortunately It doesn't work :(

```
> A
  A B C
X 1 0 0
Y 0 2 0
Z 0 0 3
> scaleMatrix(A, 2)
> A
  A B C
X 1 0 0
Y 0 2 0
Z 0 0 3
```

I learned from [Rcpp FAQ, Question 5.1](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf) that Rcpp should be able to change the object I passed by value. Stealing an example from [Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/102067040) to my previous question:

```
> library(Rcpp)
> cppFunction("void inplaceMod(NumericVector x) { x = x * 2; }")
> x <- as.numeric(1:5)
> inplaceMod(x)
> x
[1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

I'm confused: it is possible to modify a `NumericVector` in-place, but not a `NumericMatrix`?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Do you really want to modify `A` in place? Your code currently does copy A.

Comment: @Roland Yes, I do want to modify `A` in-place. The question made a wrong assumption and has been updated. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can preserve the row and column names by using `NumericVector` instead of `NumericMatrix`, keeping in mind that a matrix in R is just a vector with attached dimensions. You can do this switch either when going from R to C++ (`scaleVector` below) or within C++ (`scaleMatrix` below taken from a now deleted answer by **@Roland**):

```r
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
NumericVector scaleVector(NumericVector& A, double x) {
    A = A * x;
    return A;
}')

cppFunction('
NumericMatrix scaleMatrix(NumericMatrix& A, double x) {
    NumericVector B = A;
    B = B * x;
    return A;
}')
```

If one applies these two function to your matrix, the row and column names are preserved. However, the matrix is not changed in place:

```r
A <- diag(1:3)
rownames(A) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
colnames(A) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

scaleMatrix(A, 2)
#>   A B C
#> X 2 0 0
#> Y 0 4 0
#> Z 0 0 6
scaleVector(A, 2)
#>   A B C
#> X 2 0 0
#> Y 0 4 0
#> Z 0 0 6
A
#>   A B C
#> X 1 0 0
#> Y 0 2 0
#> Z 0 0 3
```

The reason for that is that `diag(1:3)` is actually an integer matrix, so a copy is made when you transfer it to a *numeric* matrix (or vector):

```r
is.integer(A)
#> [1] TRUE
```

If one uses a numeric matrix to begin with, modification is done in place:

```r
A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
rownames(A) <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
colnames(A) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

scaleMatrix(A, 2)
#>   A B C
#> X 2 0 0
#> Y 0 4 0
#> Z 0 0 6
scaleVector(A, 2)
#>   A B  C
#> X 4 0  0
#> Y 0 8  0
#> Z 0 0 12
A
#>   A B  C
#> X 4 0  0
#> Y 0 8  0
#> Z 0 0 12
```

Comment: Possibly because of ALTREP?

Comment: @Roland I though about it, but my last status was that Rcpp isn't ALTREP aware. However, I just realized the original `A` is actually an integer matrix ...

Comment: @RalfStubner I have tried `A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))` (see updated question), but surprisingly it isn't modified in-place either...

Comment: @RalfStubner Oh I see. I thought you were using `NumericMatrix`, but you actually used `NumericVector`.

Comment: @RalfStubner Probably a little off-topic, but what if `A` has to be a `NumericMatrix`? In my application, `A` is created in C++ code instead of passed in from R, plus it is meant to be returned as a `NumericMatrix`. Would you recommend casting with something like `as<NumericVector>` and then casting the result back? Anyway, if the content of a `NumericMatrix` is stored in a continuous chunk of memory (at least in R, a matrix is simply a vector with `dim`), then the best way is probably to scale each element with a for loop, but can I access the internal member of  a `NumericMatrix`?

Comment: @nalzok I deleted my answer which did that, but you can just do `NumericVector B = A;` and modify `B`. If will also modify `A` in place (because `A` is a vector internally).

Comment: @Roland Great, I suppose aliasing is both convenient and cheap. Thanks sir!

Comment: @Roland I have resurrected that bit of code so that users with <10K can see it in action as well.

Comment: I quite liked your code. Can you please show both (in particular useful for beginners).

Comment: @Roland Good idea!