# Can I modify a row in-place with Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, performance, matrix, rcpp

Say, I would like to increase the first row of a matrix by one. The obvious approach is `A.row(0) = A.row(0) + 1;`, but it creates a new row instead of modifying the existing one, and may cause some performance issue when the matrix is large.

From a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818049/how-to-scale-a-numericmatrix-in-place-with-rcpp), I learned that I can do a point aliasing, but it only works for the whole matrix, not for individual rows.

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('
void increaseFirstRow(NumericMatrix& A) {
    NumericVector B = A.row(0);
    B = B + 1;
}')
A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
increaseFirstRow(A)
```

The output is shown below. Note that the first row is not changed.

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    0    0    3
```

Comment: You can always code it with a loop.

Comment: For R, just like many other systems, data is organized differently.  A "matrix" is just a contiguous chunk of memory with appropriate indexing -- it really is a vector underneath. As such, no distinct "new row" exists. I think  you may be chasing a non-issue, or confused about another aspect.  You functions creates _a new object_ and increases that -- not the same as an in-place increase.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I know my function increases the new object, and that's exactly why I'm posting this question: my intention is to make `B` a pointer/alias/view to the corresponding elements in `A`, so that changes to `B` are reflected in `A`.

Comment: Your code does not do what you want to do -- in essence you are hoping / guessing / praying that `B` be a view into `A`.  But it isn't, and we never said if were. And so it doesn't.  See below for a working example that is even simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the formulation above, I think you wanted to obtain a reference to specific parts of the matrix. The following work across matrix types:

```cpp
*Matrix::Row = x( 0 , Rcpp::_);  // first row
*Matrix::Column = x( Rcpp::_ , 0); // first column
*Matrix::Sub = x( Rcpp::Range(0, 1) , Rcpp::Range(2, 3)); // first 2 rows and 3 -4th column.
```

In your case, that would be:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void row_ref(Rcpp::NumericMatrix M) {
    // Create a reference to the 1st row in M.
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix::Row x = M.row(0);
    // Increase the first row in M.
    x = x + 10; 
}
```

Example:

```
(A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    2    0
# [3,]    0    0    3

row_ref(A)

A
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   11   10   10
# [2,]    0    2    0
# [3,]    0    0    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution in RcppArmadillo, and, following an edit, in Rcpp itself:

#### Code with Example

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void incRow(arma::mat& M) {
  M.row(0) = M.row(0) + 1;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void incRow2(Rcpp::NumericMatrix M) {
  M(0,Rcpp::_) = M(0,Rcpp::_) + 1;
}


/*** R
A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
incRow(A)
A
incRow2(A)
A
*/
```

#### Output

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("/tmp/armarow.cpp")

R> A <- diag(c(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))

R> incRow(A)

R> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    1    1
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    0    0    3

R> incRow2(A)

R> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    2    2
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    0    0    3
R>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks Dirk! Actually, I want to make a feature request here: can you implement a syntax sugar in Rcpp so that `A.row(i) += 1;` increase the corresponding row by one? It won't be super hard, as you just need to write a loop and handle the indices; it can't break existing code either, as the `+=` operator is still unimplemented; it also makes sense, because otherwise `A.row(i) = A.row(i) + 1;` makes an unnecessary implicit copy. I mean, of course people can write a loop or use RcppArmadillo, but that adds complexity to their code.

Comment: Feel free to write a pull request that does that, but be prepared to also demonstrate that it has no ill effects on the 1794 known reverse dependencies of Rcpp.